# Is it possible to implement a BubbleSort with only one cycle? (Not recursive)

Tags: java, python, algorithm

What Im trying to implement is a BubbleSort/similar algorithm, but with just one single cycle.
What that means is, I want to change this:

```
for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    for(j = i+1; j < N; j++)
        //code
```

into this:

```
    for (ij = 0; ij < N * (N - 1) / 2; ij++)
        i = ?
        j = ?
        //code
```

The problem is, I need to implement the values of 'i' and 'j' manually. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but why would you want to do this?

Comment: Mainly, for my own interest. It's obviously not useful at all in the real world.

Comment: I would say no.   Yeah it will sort a little bit with one pass...but you'll need multiple passes to sort a list of items...

Comment: You could do an integer division of `ij` by `N`. Result will be `i` and the remainder will be `j`. Or maybe the other way around

Comment: also you're declaring a variable ij and not declaring two variables i and j....

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj Ok, so one pass in the sense that the pass counter resets...I see how that might work.

Comment: Ok, I removed variable declarations for clarity. Sorry if I didn't make myself completely clear but the algorithm doesn't neccesarily have to be a sorter, so the rest of the code is irrelevant, I just need the values of 'i' and 'j'.

Comment: The complexity remains O(n^2) even if you do the indexing computations yourself rather than leaving them to your compiler.

Comment: Hi @Ollie Jones, yes I know, I don't intend for this implementation to be of any use.

Comment: The issue you will run into is that in your attempt to do bubble sort in one pass, you're no longer doing bubble sort. You'll probably find a way to sort it. But, it won't be bubble sorting.

Comment: @David, you can still do a bubble sort. It doesn't matter how many loops you have, but you still need to advance your indexes in the correct way.

Comment: Ah, I assumed he was going to keep the loop to n, where n is the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant `i+1`, not `1+1`, the  code

```
for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    for(j = i+1; j < N; j++)
        //code
```

is equivalent to

```
int k = 2 * N - 1;
for (int ij = 0; ij < N * (N - 1) / 2; ij++) {
    int i = (int) Math.floor((k - Math.sqrt(k * k - 8 * ij)) / 2);
    int j = i + 1 + ij - (k - i) * i / 2;
    //code
}
```

This is completely pointless though...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
while  (ij < N * (N - 1) / 2) {
    j = (j + 1) % N;
    if (j==0)
        i++;
}
```

I don't see the benefit though

Comment: If j is 0, you need to correct j as well, since it starts at (the new) i + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a while-loop version, though I also don't see the point. Generally, you can turn almost anything into one loop by having a boolean that indicates whether to continue, and various if-tests to decide what to do inside the loop. If applied to a naturally nested loop algorithm, the result will be less readable and maintainable than using multiple loops.

```
  public static void weirdSort(int[] data) {
    boolean sortDone = false;
    boolean swapDone = false;
    if (data.length < 2) {
      // Lengths 0 and 1 create special cases, and are already sorted.
      return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (!sortDone) {
      if (data[i] > data[i + 1]) {
        swapDone = true;
        int temp = data[i + 1];
        data[i + 1] = data[i];
        data[i] = temp;
      }
      i++;
      if (i == data.length - 1) {
        sortDone = !swapDone;
        swapDone = false;
        i = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```